# How can I use the new `git switch` syntax to create a new branch?

Tags: git

I am used to `git checkout -b branchname` to switch to a new branch named `branchname`. How do I do the same with `git switch`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you don't even (always) need the `--create` option when creating a new branch with [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

if that branch matches a remote tracking one, it will create a local branch, and automatically track the remote one!

Meaning a simple `git switch <branch>` is enough.

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
$ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

> If the branch exists in multiple remotes and one of them is named by the `checkout.defaultRemote` configuration variable, we’ll use that one for the purposes of disambiguation, even if the `<branch>` isn’t unique across all remotes.
>   Set it to e.g. `checkout.defaultRemote=origin` to always checkout remote branches from there if `<branch>` is ambiguous but exists on the `origin` remote.
>   See also [`checkout.defaultRemote` in `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-checkoutdefaultRemote).

Plus, if you switch by mistake to a remote tracking branch, it fails (as opposed to `git checkout`, which would create a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) from said remote branch!)

```
git switch origin/master
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'
```

Vs.

```
git checkout origin/master
Note: switching to 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state
```

Comment: Hmm, `git switch newbranch` results in `fatal: invalid reference: newbranch` for me.

Comment: @TaylorKline I suppose because `newbranch` name does not match any of the `remotes/origin/<branches>` names. If that is the case, you would need `git switch -c newbranch`, as you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 11):

The syntax for creating a new branch with `git switch` is `git switch -c branchname` or `git switch --create branchname`.