# warning: Not setting branch master as its own upstream

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I am trying to set git branch upstream but getting below warning.

#### Command

```
git checkout master
git branch --set-upstream-to master
```

> warning: Not setting branch master as its own upstream.

How can I solve it?

Does that mean it already being tracing correct remote branch `master`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be:

```
 git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

But if `origin/master` is there, the [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_description) should have tracked it already.

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name and `--no-guess` is not specified, treat as equivalent to:

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

With Git 2.23+, you would use [`git switch master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) instead of `checkout`, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124339/6309).

Comment: Why would anyone want to set a local branch as the upstream?

Comment: @Unknow0059 maybe because that person has missed the concept of "upstream" and "remotes", as defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309

Comment: So it's technically possible for you to set any repository as the upstream, it's just not the convention.

Comment: @Unknow0059 there can be cases to do so, like one working offline for some experimental works.